# Propositional logic simplification exercise

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to simplify this to use just one of $\neg,\wedge,\vee,\leftrightarrow,\rightarrow$ using proportional laws $\neg\,[\neg\,(p∧r)∨(\neg\,p∧q)]∧(p∨r)$ but I have no luck.

Comment: It is the same as $P\land R$

Answer (score 1):

You need to know: $\neg(a\wedge b)=\neg a\vee\neg b$ and $\neg(a\vee b)=\neg a\wedge\neg b$.

So you start by simplifying to $$(p\wedge r)\wedge\neg(\neg p\wedge q)\wedge(p\vee r)$$ then to $$(p\wedge r)\wedge(p\vee\neg q)\wedge(p\vee r)$$ But $p\wedge r$ implies both $p\vee\neg q$ and $p\vee r$, so the expression reduces to $$p\wedge r$$

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your answer. I dont understand what do you mean when you say "implies". Based in what proportional logic rule we get the p∧r?